# How do i get rid of the extra columns?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I just made a list of clients , got the clients details from the database, added them to a list, then added the list to the DataGrid but I get so many extra columns ! Here is my DataGrid xaml code :

```
<DataGrid  x:Name="dataGridC" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="150" Width="1000" />
```

---

And this is my code-behind:

```
var cn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\G_D_C v2\G_D_C v2\G_D_C.mdb");
                cn.Open();

                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();


                cmd.CommandText = "select * from [client]";
                cmd.Connection = cn;

             //   OleDbDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    using (OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            int ID = reader.GetInt32(0);
                            string nom_cs = reader.GetString(1);
                            int num_tel = reader.GetInt32(2);
                            int fax = reader.GetInt32(3);
                            string adresse = reader.GetString(4);

                            client c = new client(ID, nom_cs, num_tel, fax, adresse);
                            lsc.Add(c);
                        }
                    }

              //  dataGridC.ItemsSource = rd;


                  dataGridC.ItemsSource = lsc;
```

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XL7tp.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" />`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx

Right because you didn't specify what you wanted to show up.  `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` will not generate the columns that are present in your `DataGrid.ItemSource` because that property just told it not to generate any columns...  the rows might show but nothing will actually be visible.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Grid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="ID" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding nom_cs}" Header="Nom CS" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding num_tel}" Header="Num Tel" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding fax}" Header="Fax" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Adresse}" Header="Adresse" />
    </DataGrid.Columns> 
</DataGrid>
```